# Override PHP options with .htaccess, DSO works (suPHP doesn't)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, suphp

I am using .htaccess in a sub directory as below:

`php_value apc.cache_by_default 0`

But this throws an error, if i use DSO, then it works.

I understand with suPHP I have to ovveride with a php.ini file - how would i achieve disabling the single module without specifying the entire ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You have to get the whole ini that you currently have and edit only what you want to be different.